# Trying to create a bitmap from a ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: android

I have code that loads a png file from a url into a ByteArrayOutputStream.  Now I want to make this into a bitmap so I can draw it.  I tried
    Bitmap bBack=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(output);,
but BitMapFactory will not take in a yteArrayOutputStream.

How can I creat a bitmap from a ByteArrayOutputStream object?,
code

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://stage.master.embryooptions.healthbanks.com/siteassets/24/ShadyGrove-logo.png");
    InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
       output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//   HOW DO I GET A BITMAP?????????
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//                  Bitmap bBack=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(output);
    return "";
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to create a Bitmap object from an image downloaded from your URL, then ByteArrayOutputStream isn't necessary.  All you need is this:

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

You can look at the developer page for [BitmapFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Below should work for you:

```
byte[] bitmapData = output.toByteArray();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapData , 0, bitmapData.length);
```

**Note:** Be carefull on bitmap loading. Always use `BitmapFactory.Options` while decoding to bitmap to prevent memory related errors.

[Read more.](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)